# Trying to access id class method from swift

Tags: ios, swift, soundcloud

I'm trying to access the following method from the Soundcloud iOS SDK from my Swift code without success (the method seems not accessible and autocomplete do not show it too). Any hint?

```
+ (id)   performMethod:(SCRequestMethod)aMethod
            onResource:(NSURL *)resource
       usingParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
           withAccount:(SCAccount *)account
sendingProgressHandler:(SCRequestSendingProgressHandler)progressHandler
       responseHandler:(SCRequestResponseHandler)responseHandler;
```

Comment: Show your code? without success means what we have to understand. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not even getting the ability to see the method from my Swift code (autocompletion etc.) My bridging header is fine.

Comment: is that class is available in your swift file

Comment: It is a class method and yes the .h file in which it is contained is in my Bridging header so it is accessible in my swift code. (the class is called SCRequest.h, I can call  SCRequest but I cannot call this specific class method)

Comment: How does your method call look like in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

In my bridging header file I included

```
#import "SCAPI.h"
```

and now to make any class methods I simply call SCSoundCloud.* or SCRequest.* and the autocomplete is fine. Did you add the SoundCloud libraries under Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

That class method on `SCRequest` is bridged like this:

```
class func perform(_           aMethod: SCRequestMethod,
                   onResource resource: URL!,
            usingParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]!,
                          with account: SCAccount!,
sendingProgressHandler progressHandler: SCRequestSendingProgressHandler!,
             responseHandler: SCRequestResponseHandler!) -> Any!
```

Make sure to install the framework via CocoaPods and add `#import <CocoaSoundCloudAPI/SCAPI.h>` to your bridging header.